# Python not printing the correct results, though the results is correct

Tags: python, printing

I have loaded a file into a list

```
    line_storage = [];

    try:
        with open(file_name_and_path, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                line_storage.append(line)    # store in list
```

But when trying to convert it to string ("stringify" it):

```
 total_number_of_lines = len(line_storage)

 lineBuffer = "";
 for line_index in xrange(0, total_number_of_lines):
      lineBuffer += line_storage[line_index].rstrip('\n') # append line after removing newline
```

The print is not showing me the full content, but only the last line. Though, len(lineBuffer) is correct.

The file contents is:
      `....`
      `[04.01] Test 1:`
      `You should be able to read this.`
      `[04.02] Test 2:`
      `....`
      `=========================================================== EOF`

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text lines probably end in `\r\n`, not just `\n`. By removing the `\n`, you are leaving the `\r` at the end of each line. When you print this to the terminal, each line will overwrite the previous line because `\r` only moves the cursor back to the beginning of the current line.

The solution is probably to use `.rstrip('\r\n')`.

Comment: or just use `rstrip` without any arguments

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That will strip *any* whitespace, and it's possible that the OP wants to preserve spaces/tabs at the end of lines.